# IconData takes a long time to load and does not show icons

Tags: flutter, android-studio

The list with icons (IconData) takes a very long time to load, about a minute. Previously, there was no such problem - the list was loaded in a couple of seconds. I tried reinstalling Flutter and Android Studio on an SSD, but it didn't help.

How can this be fixed?

[image]

```
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7784292, built on October 1, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 16
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.intellij.marketplace, Dart, com.thoughtworks.gauge, org.jetbrains.kotlin, io.flutter, org.intellij.plugins.markdown

Dart: 203.8452
Flutter: 62.0.1
```

Comment: Is this only happening for IconData list?

Comment: @developerjamiu, yes. For example, the list of colors is loaded instantly

Comment: Yes, same issue for me as well. I updated to Arctic Fox and now IconData suggestion is stuck at loading. I am using Macbook Air M1

Comment: Same issue here. I'm trying to see if there's already an open issue for this on Github, but it's kinda hard to filter through them, they're thousands

Comment: I have the same issue too

Comment: FIY, I updated Android studio and both Dart and Flutter plugins, and the issue disappeared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developers have fixed this bug in one of the recent updates.

Answer (score 0):

only need to update your android Studio, go to Setting-update-check Now

then update if need it will work smoothly after that